# Magento 2 sales rule to offer the cheapest one of a product selection

Tags: magento2, magento-rules

I've been searching and testing for some weeks now but I really need some help figuring out a way to implement the following price rules. It seems rather simple but I'm strugling a bit.

The goal is to have a product selection added in the price rule conditions and to set a percentage discount in the cheapest one.

Does anyone have some idea in order to implement this?

Thanks

The closest I got was the price rule to offer one unit of each of those products and not just one, neither the cheapest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.